# Selenium java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in starting the driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried the code below to open a chrome webdriver and then open google.com using it:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

 public class Hook{

  private WebDriver driver;

  public void testInitializer(){
    File file = new 
        File(Application.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResource("driver/chromedriver.exe").getFile());
    String driverPath=file.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("Webdriver is in path: "+driverPath);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverPath);
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
}

 public Hook() {

     testInitializer();
     driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
 }

}
```

But it complains in the line:

```
driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

with the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter;
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.<init>(UrlChecker.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>
    at com.example.demo.Hook.testInitializer(Hook.java:20)
```

And here is the complete dependencies:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
            </dependency>
```

I am wondering, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What selenium version are you using? Looks like some dependencies need updating. See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5223

Comment: Version 3.4.0 works for me just fine.

Comment: @KamyarParastesh What does `System.out.println("Webdriver is in path: "+driverPath);` prints for you?

Answer (score 0):

See last line of Exception `at com.example.demo.Hook.testInitializer(Hook.java:20)`, it is run time exception this is because your class is missing `main` method.

Quoting [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) (JLS) `A Java virtual machine starts execution by invoking the method main of some specified class, passing it a single argument, which is an array of strings`. More specifically, it is looking for a method that should be declared as ...

```
public class Hook {
    ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // body of main method follows
        ...
    }
}
```